# angular 2 how to create the Multiple tabs in *ngfor loop?

Tags: angular, css

```
<div  *ngFor="let post of posts ;let i = index " >
    <div class="tabs_main">
        <ul class="tabs_ul">
            <li class="tabs_li active" (click)="explore_tab_one(post.id)"> Questions </li>
            <li class="tabs_li" (click)="explore_tab_two(post.id)"> Opinions</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab_content active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h3> Tab 1 </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab_content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h3> Tab 2 </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to create the multiple tabs in *ngfor loop?

my expectation is click the Opinions , display the tab 2 and toggle the class active , only the first loop

Comment: if i understand , your code create multiple tabs , u just don't know how to set the first tab active in the loop , is this your question ?

Comment: yes and also if i click the second tab only the first loop tabs add and remove the active class.

Comment: i think the active class will be changed automatically when u toggle it

Comment: yes  if i click one another one is toggle